"SRE module mismatch" When Using subprocess.call only
I am working on a project that uses the DeepFilterNet library.  My main Python environment is still Python 3.8, but I created a venv for it using Python 3.11.  Despite creating a venv for this and having it work hands on in the environment, I get an "SRE module mismatch" that I just can't seem to solve when calling it from another script in a different environment.
Python venv was created like this:
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv deepFilterNet
Using deepFilterNet works when hands on activating the environment in Windows commandline, or even if doing something like this in the commandline without activating the environment:
"D:\Python Venvs\deepFilterNet\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\untitled\deepFilterNet.py"
The problem is when I try to use subprocess.call using PyCharm, which is running my Python 3.8 environment and another script that's using it to make the call, I keep getting a "SRE module mismatch" error.  I've tried looking all over for help with this error but nothing seems to work and I've spent 2 hours going nowhere.
Script that I'm trying to run to call my deepFilterNet.py project file:
import subprocess

result = subprocess.call(["D:/Python Venvs/deepFilterNet/Scripts/python.exe", "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/untitled/deepFilterNet.py"])
print(result)

Traceback Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\PycharmProjects\untitled\deepFilterNet.py", line 9, in <module>
1
    from df.enhance import enhance, init_df, load_audio, save_audio
  File "D:\Python Venvs\deepFilterNet\Lib\site-packages\df\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import config
  File "D:\Python Venvs\deepFilterNet\Lib\site-packages\df\config.py", line 2, in <module>
    import string
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\string.py", line 52, in <module>
    import re as _re
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert _sre.MAGIC == MAGIC, "SRE module mismatch"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

I noticed it's referencing the Python 3.8 installation for the re.py and string.py, which I wonder is a helpful clue to someone who is more familiar with this issue.  I did notice my sys.path list in the venv made reference to my Python 3.8 directories as well.  I did try to delete them at runtime from sys.path but that didn't seem to work either, I don't think it was able to find the string library as a result.
